# What is sub-millisecond precision?

Tags: ios, nstimeinterval

I'm working through an animations tutorial which introduced closures. I began to search through Apple's reference docs for what [TimeInterval](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timeinterval) is. I'm curious to know what is sub-millisecond precision?

Comment: It means less than a millisecond. Is this a trick question?

Comment: @matt no, I really didn't understand and didn't get much information from a Google search.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means it is more precise than 0.001 seconds (one millisecond or one one-thousandth of a second). You can store a value such as 0.0005 (five ten-thousandths or half of a millisecond).